# Node.JS extracting class comments

Tags: javascript, node.js, comments

I have a Node.JS project that I'm working on, and a very specific feature of it needs to read all of the JS files in a directory, extract their class comments (possibly class name too), then store this information in an array of objects to later convert into markdown.

My question is *what's the best way to extract these components such as class names and class comments?*

I've thought about reading the file and parsing the syntax, but why reinvent the wheel? If there are good tools for extracting specific comments, or clever algorithms of parsing the JS file, I'd like to hear them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try one of these libs:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-comments

https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-comments

https://www.npmjs.com/package/elsen-js-comments

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Seems like `js-comments` is simple enough and gets the job done!

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool that does exactly this! Check out jsDoc.
https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc

Building HTML webpages from comments is as simple as doing:

```
npm i -g jsdoc
jsdoc yourFile.js
```

And of course this can be combined with grunt/gulp...

Comment: Is jsdoc limited to HTML webpages, or can it generate markdown as well?

Comment: It looks like it!
http://usejsdoc.org/plugins-markdown.html#enabling-the-markdown-plugin

Comment: Nice! Well I'll have to keep this in mind in case my current strategy doesn't work. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into parsers that **convert your code into an [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)**.

For example, [Esprima](http://esprima.org/#) can help you parse ES6 JavaScript and extract identifiers and comments.

Have a look at [this live demo](http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html?code=%2F**%0A%20*%0A%20*%20This%20is%20a%20test%20class%0A%20*%0A%20*%2F%0Aclass%20Foo%20%7B%0A%09bar()%20%7B%0A%09%09console.log('foobar')%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D). For the following class, the AST below will be generated:

```
/**
 *
 * This is a test class
 *
 */
class Foo {
    bar() {
        console.log('foobar');
    }
}
```

---

```
{
    "type": "Program",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "ClassDeclaration",
            "id": {
                "type": "Identifier",
                "name": "Foo"
            },
            "superClass": null,
            "body": {
                        ...
                    }
                ]
            },
            "leadingComments": [
                {
                    "type": "Block",
                    "value": "*\n *\n * This is a test class\n *\n ",
                    "range": [
                        0,
                        37
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "sourceType": "script"
}
```

Comment: Definitely a good way of parsing the classes, but as long as I only need comments it might be overkill. I will keep this in mind though, thanks!